Is there any way to perform a pivot on a Polars LazyFrame?
I am trying to perform a pivot operation on a lazy polars dataframe.
This means, if I collect my data, I can do the pivot:
df = pl.read_parquet(path,low_memory=True)
pivoted_df = df.pivot(index=["ind1", "ind2", "ind3", "ind4"], columns="my_signal", values="Value", aggregate_function="mean")

These lines of code work.
However, if i am using a lazy dataframe by calling this :
df = pl.scan_parquet(path,low_memory=True)


I cannot find a way to perform the same algorithm. .pivot cannot be applied on a lazy object.
IMPORTANT: I do not want at any point to collect my data with df.collect() as I have a very large dataset that doesn't fit in memory.
I want to save the lazy dataframe at the end with pivoted_df .sink_parquet(), so yeah I don't want at any point to collect the data.
Thank you in advance !
I have tried to use .group_by instead of .pivot:
grouped_df = df.group_by(["["ind1", "ind2", "ind3", "ind4"])
transformed_df = grouped_df.agg(**{f"{col}_mean": pl.col("Value").mean()  for col in pl.col('my_signal').unique()})

But I am getting the error 'Expr' object is not iterable which is normal as pl.col('full_signal_name').unique() is an expression.
Any alternatives ?
Example:
df :
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ ind1 ┆ ind2 ┆ ind3 ┆ ind4 ┆ my_signal ┆ Value │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str       ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════╪═══════╡
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ a         ┆ 1     │
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ a         ┆ 1     │
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ a         ┆ 1     │
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ b         ┆ 2     │
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ b         ┆ 2     │
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ b         ┆ 2     │
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ c         ┆ 3     │
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ c         ┆ 3     │
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ c         ┆ 3     │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────┴───────┘

pivoted_df:
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ ind1 ┆ ind2 ┆ ind3 ┆ ind4 ┆ a    ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ f64  ┆ f64 ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ 1.0  ┆ 2.0 ┆ null │
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ null ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘


It would be easiest to answer if you'd provide an example dataframe with the expected output.

Example is added, thanks :)

There's some advice in the documentation of pivot():

Note that pivot is only available in eager mode. If you know the unique column values in advance, you can use polars.LazyFrame.groupby() to get the same result as above in lazy mode

adjusting this example to your use case:
index = pl.col("ind1", "ind2", "ind3", "ind4")
columns = pl.col("my_signal")
values = pl.col("Value")
unique_column_values = list(df.unique("my_signal").select("my_signal").collect().to_series())
aggregate_function = lambda col: col.mean()

df.group_by(index).agg(
    aggregate_function(values.filter(columns == value)).alias(value)
    for value in unique_column_values
).collect()

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ ind1 ┆ ind2 ┆ ind3 ┆ ind4 ┆ b   ┆ a    ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ 2.0 ┆ null ┆ 3.0  │
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ 2.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ null │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘

I was trying to find an alternative way of doing it as well. As we want to have dynamic columns, natural way would be to use unnest() method of Struct. So intermediate goal would be to end up with DataFrame like this:
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────────────┐
│ ind1 ┆ ind2 ┆ ind3 ┆ ind4 ┆ my_signal      │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---            │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ struct[3]      │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪════════════════╡
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ {2.0,3.0,null} │
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ {2.0,null,1.0} │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────────┘

It's relatively easy to get fairly close to this intermediate goal:
(
    df
    .group_by("ind1", "ind2", "ind3", "ind4", "my_signal")
    .mean()
    .group_by("ind1", "ind2", "ind3", "ind4")
    .agg(pl.struct(pl.col("my_signal"),pl.col("Value")))
    .collect()
)

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────────────────────┐
│ ind1 ┆ ind2 ┆ ind3 ┆ ind4 ┆ my_signal              │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                    │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ list[struct[2]]        │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪════════════════════════╡
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ [{"b",2.0}, {"c",3.0}] │
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ [{"a",1.0}, {"b",2.0}] │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────────────────┘

So now we only need to find the way to convert list of structs [{"b",2.0}, {"c",3.0}] to struct {a:2.0,b:3.0}. However, I could not find an easy way to do that. Maybe you can do it via list_eval()?
There's a bit ugly brute force way though - go into eager mode within a group and use pivot and convert back to struct. I had to add a dummy column cause pivot requires index column and in my cause I don't need it.
def transform(x):
    return (
        x
        .list.explode().struct.unnest()
        .with_columns(pl.lit(1).alias('i'))
        .pivot(index="i", values="Value", columns="my_signal", aggregate_function='mean')
        .drop('i')
        .select(pl.struct(pl.all()))
        .item()
    )

(
    df
    .group_by("ind1", "ind2", "ind3", "ind4")
    .agg(pl.struct(pl.col("my_signal"),pl.col("Value")))
    .with_columns(pl.col("my_signal").map_elements(transform))
    .unnest('my_signal')
    .collect()
)

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ ind1 ┆ ind2 ┆ ind3 ┆ ind4 ┆ b   ┆ c    ┆ a    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ fff  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ null │
│ www  ┆ xxx  ┆ yyy  ┆ zzz  ┆ 2.0 ┆ null ┆ 1.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘

Maybe there's a better way of converting [{"b",2.0}, {"c",3.0}] to {a:2.0,b:3.0}, I need to look into it later.

Thank you for your reply! The solution would work for a typical dataframe. However, I have a very large dataset, thus, the .collect() in unique_column_values makes my machine crash. This is why I need to keep a lazy dataframe through the whole code so I can just sink it later on  as parquets.
Maybe I am asking for an impossible solution I don't know :/

I've added some (ugly) alternative solution, you could also try that.

But logically speaking - before you start sinking parquet, you need to know all the columns, and to know all the columns you have to scan at least my_signal column of the whole dataset. I don't think you can do it in pure streaming solution. So, probably my alternative solution is not going to work as well.
Maybe you could revise your output format?

hmm, I wasn't aware of this issue of knowing columns to be able to sink. I have a large code where I am doing many operations on the lazy dataframe, and in each step i can sink my parquets with no issue.
However, I have tried your solution and I am getting an error once I try sinking :
polars.exceptions.InvalidOperationError: sink_Parquet(ParquetWriteOptions { compression: Zstd(None), statistics: true, row_group_size: None, data_pagesize_limit: None, maintain_order: true }) not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'

I have looked online and it's apparently the unnest that can't be sinked after !

Found it ! :D This works !

